# C - Segmented sieve losing prime numbers

Tags: c, sieve-of-eratosthenes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void sieve(unsigned int up, unsigned int low, unsigned char primes[]);

main()
{
    unsigned int low, up;
    unsigned int steps;
    scanf("%d",&steps);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<steps;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&low,&up);

        unsigned char v[up-low];
        sieve (up, low, v);
        for(unsigned int j=0; j<up-low+1; j++){
            if (v[j] == 1){
                printf("%d\n",low+j);
            }
        }   
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
void sieve(unsigned int up, unsigned int low, unsigned char primes[])
{
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<up-low+1;i++){
        primes[i]=1;
    }

    for (unsigned int i=2;i<sqrt(up+1);i++) {
        for (int j=((low/i)*i)+i;j<up+1;j+=i){
                primes[j-low] = 0;


        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find prime numbers from particular range. I'm using segmented sieve of Erastothenes but unfortunately its losing some prime numbers, it's because of:

```
for (int j=((low/i)*i)+i;j<up+1;j+=i){
                    primes[j-low] = 0;
```

When `i` becomes bigger than my lower limit sieve function starts marking prime numbers with `0` value and after all they are not present in my stdout.

> e.g stdin:
>   1
>   2 1000
>   e.g stdout:
>   2
>   37  it loses all prime numbers between 2 and 37
>   41
>   43
>   ...

There is one thing more the lower limit value is always recognized as prime number by the algorithm.

> e.g stdin:
>   4 10
>
> e.g stdout:
>   4
>   5
>   7

I need some help with tweaking my algorithm to mark this numbers properly because after couple hours im really clueless what conditions i need to make it work.

Comment: `for (unsigned int i=0;i<up-low+1;i++){primes[i]=1;}` does not match `unsigned char v[up-low];`

Comment: it's char array of 0 or 1 values, up-low determines size of this array, what is not matching here?

Comment: the last valid index of `unsigned char v[up-low];` is `up-low-1`, but you are accessing `primes[up-low]` in the loop.

Comment: the posted code does not (cleanly) compile.  Amongst other things, the `main()` function ALWAYS uses `int` as the return type (regardless of what Visual Studio will accept

Comment: the function: `sieve()` contains several 'implicit' conversions between `signed int` and `unsigned int`  You should correct those problems.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: is this a item from `online code judge` or similar?  If so, should provide a link in the question so we are all working from the same page.

Comment: this line: `        unsigned char v[up-low];` is problematic as each iteration through the loop can have different values for `up` and `low`.  ALSO, this allocation is 1 short of what is actually needed (for instance, what if `low` is 2 and `up` is 2,  then the allocation would be `unsigned char v[0]` which would be an error

Comment: regarding this line: `for (unsigned int i=2; i<sqrt(up+1); i++)`  if `low` is 2 and `up` is 2, then `i<sqrt(up+1)`  results in the loop never being executed (even though 2 is a prime) because sqrt(3) is less than 2 Therefore there is a basic logic error in the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an off-by-one error.  Your array is not big enough to hold flags for all the elements.  Make it one larger:

```
unsigned char v[up-low+1];
```

Now the main problem is in your loop:

```
for (unsigned int i=2;i<sqrt(up+1);i++) {
    for (int j=((low/i)*i)+i;j<up+1;j+=i){
        primes[j-low] = 0;
    }
}
```

You're not starting at the correct index.  In the case of `low==4`, the first iteration of the inner loop sets `j` to `((4/2)*2)+2 == (2*2)+2 == 4*2 == 6`, so you're skipping 4 entirely.

Keep it simple.  Start `j` at `i*2`.  In the loop skip any value of `j` less than `low`:

```
for (unsigned int i=2;i<sqrt(up+1);i++) {
    for (unsigned int j=i*2;j<up+1;j+=i){
        if (j < low) continue;
        primes[j-low] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to analyze my c++ solution for segmented Sieve, as there is not a lot of segmented sieve correct implementations over the net. I hope it can help you understand how it works. Cheers!

```
void sito_delta( int delta, std::vector<int> &res)
{

std::unique_ptr<int[]> results(new int[delta+1]);
for(int i = 0; i <= delta; ++i)
    results[i] = 1;

int pierw = sqrt(delta);
for (int j = 2; j <= pierw; ++j)
{
    if(results[j])
    {
        for (int k = 2*j; k <= delta; k+=j)
        {
            results[k]=0;
        }
    }
}

for (int m = 2; m <= delta; ++m)
    if (results[m])
    {
        res.push_back(m);
        std::cout<<","<<m;
    }
};
void sito_segment(int n,std::vector<int> &fiPri)
{
int delta = sqrt(n);

if (delta>10)
{
    sito_segment(delta,fiPri);
   // COmpute using fiPri as primes
   // n=n,prime = fiPri;
      std::vector<int> prime=fiPri;
      int offset = delta;
      int low = offset;
      int high = offset * 2;
      while (low < n)
      {
          if (high >=n ) high = n;
          int mark[offset+1];
          for (int s=0;s<=offset;++s)
              mark[s]=1;

          for(int j = 0; j< prime.size(); ++j)
          {
            int lowMinimum = (low/prime[j]) * prime[j];
            if(lowMinimum < low)
                lowMinimum += prime[j];

            for(int k = lowMinimum; k<=high;k+=prime[j])
                mark[k-low]=0;
          }

          for(int i = low; i <= high; i++)
              if(mark[i-low])
              {
                fiPri.push_back(i);
                std::cout<<","<<i;
              }
          low=low+offset;
          high=high+offset;
      }
}
else
{

std::vector<int> prime;
sito_delta(delta, prime);
//
fiPri = prime;
//
int offset = delta;
int low = offset;
int high = offset * 2;
// Process segments one by one 
while (low < n)
{
    if (high >= n) high = n;
    int  mark[offset+1];
    for (int s = 0; s <= offset; ++s)
        mark[s] = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j < prime.size(); ++j)
    {
        // find the minimum number in [low..high] that is
        // multiple of prime[i] (divisible by prime[j])
        int lowMinimum = (low/prime[j]) * prime[j];
        if(lowMinimum < low)
            lowMinimum += prime[j];

        //Mark multiples of prime[i] in [low..high]
        for (int k = lowMinimum; k <= high; k+=prime[j])
            mark[k-low] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
        if(mark[i-low])
        {
            fiPri.push_back(i);
            std::cout<<","<<i;
        }
    low = low + offset;
    high = high + offset;
}
}
};

int main()
{
std::vector<int> fiPri;
sito_segment(1013,fiPri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues raised in comments and other answers.

For the specific problem raised regarding `i>low` meaning `low/i==0` (integer arithmetic!) you should use modulo arithmetic.

The function `first_multiple()` finds the first multiple of `multiple` greater than or equal to `low`.
That's the numerical value you want to start at.

So you're loop is more like `for(unsigned j=first_multiple(low,i); //....`.

In fact you can get away with something like `for(unsigned j=first_multiple(low,i)-low; //...` if you change things around a bit. But I'll leave that as an exercise...

Remember if i>low and i is prime then the first occurrence should be skipped. You probably want different stages for before and after i<low.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned first_multiple(unsigned low, unsigned multiple){
    unsigned rem=low%multiple;//Remainder.
    if(rem==0){ // Remainder is 0 so it divides.
        return low;
    }
    return low+multiple-rem;//Round up!
}

int check(unsigned low, unsigned multiple, unsigned expect){
    unsigned result=first_multiple(low,multiple);
    if(result<low){
        return 1;
    }
    if(result==expect){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int errors=0;
    errors+=check(2,2,2);
    errors+=check(3,2,4);
    errors+=check(4,2,4);
    errors+=check(5,2,6);
    errors+=check(287456,97,287508);
    errors+=check(16,75,75);
    errors+=check(16587,1658776,1658776);
    if(errors!=0){
        printf("ERRORS!\n");
    }else{
        printf("SUCCESS!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```